# How to integrate google login via phone by just pressing yes on the device in codeigniter 5.6?

Tags: codeigniter, google-signin

I have searched solutions for this. But I am only getting tutorials for integrating google login. What I want is login to my Codeigniter web-app by entering email id and pressing yes on the mobile device every time I login to my Codeigniter [web-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZSp9.png).

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to do that it is imperative to intergrate your app with Google's OAuth Login.That is the only way your app will be able to fetch the user details from google.
Follow this link to get a simple tutorial on how to implement that.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Comment: I have already done that. But it asks me for email id and password for login. I dont want that. I just want it to ask for email ID. Then a prompt to be sent to the mobile device asking to allow access. Yes or No.